# MPLBACKEND is ingored

Tags: python, matplotlib

The environment variable MPLBACKEND seems to get ignored:

```
> MPLBACKEND=QtAgg python -c "import matplotlib.pyplot as plt; print(plt.get_backend())"
agg

> MPLBACKEND=QtAgg python -c "import matplotlib.pyplot as plt; plt.plot([1],[1]); plt.show()"
<string>:1: UserWarning: Matplotlib is currently using agg, which is a non-GUI backend, so cannot show the figure.
```

Similar with `TkAgg`. Everything is installed correctly, as setting `matplotlib.use('QtAgg')` or `matplotlib.use('TkAgg')` in code works as expected, i.e. it opens a widget with the plot.

How can I make the environment variable work?

Edit: A `matplotlibrc` in the current directory with `backend : QtAgg` or `backend : TkAgg` also has no effect.

Comment: Are you running this on a headless server?  Do any pyqt5 apps work?

Comment: Not headless. And yes, using matplotlib.use('QtAgg') in my python script opens a Qt Widget with the plot. Same for Tk.

Comment: The generalization to “qtagg” is quite new. Are you sure your version of Matplotlib supports it? Did you try qt5agg?

Comment: yes, same problem with `qt5agg`.

Comment: Try `MPLBACKEND=TkAgg python -c "import matplotlib.pyplot as plt; import os; print(os.environ.get('MPLBACKEND')); print(plt.get_backend())"`